# Querying responses to RMM-generated addresses

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Is it possible, through the use of a QueryActivity or other process, to enumerate responses sent to RMM-generated email addresses?  I'd like to be able to correlate a message send with responses to it.  I would imagine it's possible as long as the RMM-generated addresses are associated with the corresponding sends.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about querying after the fact but a sender profile could be setup with custom RMM settings that will use a Triggered Send for forwards. The email used for the Triggered Send can include the following substitution strings that can be used to identify the original message based on JobID, BatchID, and SubscriberID.  There are also substitution string used to pass through the message and details from the individual replying.

```
%%_RMM_JobID%%
%%_RMM_BatchID%%
%%_RMM_SubscriberID%%

%%_RMM_ListID%%
%%_RMM_Headers%%
%%_RMM_ReplyBodyText%%
%%_RMM_ReplyBodyHTML%%
%%_RMM_ReplySubject%%
%%_RMM_RecipientEmailAddress%%
%%_RMM_RecipientSubscriberKey%%
```